# Gradle Android, exclude dependency from another module

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an Android app, who I want to unit test. With the MVP pattern, I was able to extract a lot of classes outside of the "android world" in order to test them as plain unit tests (with Junit) inside a separate module[1].
However, I would like to log some messages from those classes. So I have tried to use `slf4j-api` with the *android* binding. With the intention to provide the *simple* binding on my tests.
But the "**test**" module start with complaining that there are two slf4j binding in the classpath and that he is using the android-binding.

So my question is, How can I exclude the `slf4j-android` dependency from the "**test**" module ?
Here is the *build.gradle* of my "**test**" module

```
evaluationDependsOn(":app")

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    def app = project(':app')

    testCompile project(path: ':app', configuration: 'debugCompile')

    def debugVariant = app.android.applicationVariants.find({it.name == 'debug'})
    testCompile debugVariant.javaCompile.classpath
    testCompile debugVariant.javaCompile.outputs.files
    testCompile files(app.plugins.findPlugin("com.android.application").getBootClasspath())

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'

}
```

[1] http://blog.blundell-apps.com/how-to-run-robolectric-junit-tests-in-android-studio/

Comment: see my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48675126/3256989

Answer (score 0):

Use the "exclude" attribute to remove dependent libraries.  Something like the following:

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' {
    exclude 'slf4j-android'
}

I'm not sure which library you need to exclude it from.  To find out, use gradle to list the library dependencies.

gradle dependencies

Comment: Thanks but it don't work. The `slf4j-android` came from the **app** project. So I must exclude it from either `testCompile project..` or one of the `debugVariant`. Let's say I have to exclude it from `debugVariant.javaCompile.classpath`. How Can I do that ?