# How to configure gradle to use logback-classic ONLY for unit tests in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, logback, slf4j

I have an Android app thich uses slf4j + logback.
Gradle file looks like this:

```
...
compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6') {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback.core.net'
}

compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback.core.net'
}

compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
```

And I have logback.xml in assets/. When I run the app logging work as expected. Recently I've decided to add new unit tests (regular, not android unit tests) but I saw that log messages are not shown.

I've added following to the gragle file:

```
testCompile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.github.tony19'
}
```

and now log messages are shown but on each run of the unit tests I get this warning:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/o/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/o/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.tony19/logback-android-classic/1.1.1-6/614c66c9ece69eef48c65a8558de4fd7266d9f69/logback-android-classic-1.1.1-6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Is there a way to specify exclusively which slf4j binding to be used for the regular app runs and which for unit tests only (or any other solution)?

Dependencies graph:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.bolyartech.forge.android:forge-android:7.1.0
|    +--- com.bolyartech.forge:base:5.1.0
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 -> 1.7.25
|    |    +--- com.darwinsys:hirondelle-date4j:1.5.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0
|    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2
|    |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.1
|    +--- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2
|    \--- net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.5.1
+--- com.bolyartech.scram_sasl:scram_sasl:2.0.1
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.8
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
+--- com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v0.9.3
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2 (*)
+--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6
+--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6
|    +--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6
|    \--- com.github.tony19:apktool-lib:1.4.4-3
|         \--- com.google.android:android:2.1_r1
|              +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|              +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|              |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|              |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|              |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
|              +--- org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1
|              +--- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2
|              \--- xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c
+--- ch.acra:acra:4.7.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 -> 26.0.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.1
|              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1 (*)
|              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.1 (*)
|              \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.1 (*)
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9 (*)
\--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.1
     |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.1
          +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.1 (*)
          \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.1 (*)


testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
+--- junit:junit:4.12
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
\--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
     \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify the module in the dependency as well?

    `testCompile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.github.tony19', module: 'logback-android-classic'
    }`
Maybe it's also `name` instead of `module`. Haven't tested it myself.

Comment: @cotnic just tried it - warning is still present...

Comment: @Henrik Yes, it gets even worst - warns that now slf4j has not 2 but 3 bindings :-)

Comment: @Ognyan: Yeah, I misunderstood the situation. Apologies. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Android Gradle Plugin 3 and above, try to use following:

```
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'   
runtimeOnly 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Dependency Scope

In the [old version](https://docs.gradle.org/2.14/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) of gradle, the dependency scope of compile will be included in all classpaths of projects, i.e. including compilation, runtime, test compilation and test execution. So the two implementations of SLF4J class will be included in test execution.

#### SLF4J Binding

And because the [implementation of SLF4J bindings](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/08/slf4j-introduction.html#binding), two bindings will causes an warning, SLF4J will randomly choose a binding, in this case, not logback.

#### Solution

So, the only way to solve the problem is to exclude logback-android from your test classpath.

In the new version of Gradle (4.0.2), we define logback-android in `runtimeElements` to avoid be used by test environment. In old version, it seems that we cann't solve this problem with gradle.

#### Ref

- [Java Library Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html)
- [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

Comment: I am awarding the bounty to this answer not because it provides solution but because it clearly states why there is no solution at this time. So we have to wait until gradle 4.0.2...

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude it on the root level, instead of the logback classic dependency:

```
configurations {
    testCompile.exclude group: 'com.github.tony19'
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that it does not have the desired effect, the warning is still present.  The problem with this solution is probably that the `android-classic` binding is part of the `compile` configuration, not `testCompile`.

Comment: testCompile inherits from the compile configuration, that is how it works, so maybe you have a different issue. Could you post your dependency graph? "dependencies" task

Comment: Forgot about this question, but there should be multiple ways to do this, they are just ugly solutions: create a separate configuration for the android-classic library and add that configuration to compileJava.classpath += configurations.androidClassic. Or do the opposite and remove from the test classpath the android library: test.classpath -= configurations.androidClassic

Answer (score 0):

Exclude tony19 library from test classpath with

```
configurations {
  testImplementation.exclude group: 'com.github.tony19'
  //with testCompile the library is not used for compilation but used for running tests
}

dependencies {
  //logging
  implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30'
  runtimeOnly 'com.github.tony19:logback-android:2.0.0'
  testImplementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version:  '1.2.11'
}
```

Using `testCompile.exclude` still give the warning

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/raiser/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5db974f19df3b652be1c75410514efb8/transformed/jetified-logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/raiser/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f97ca29862548c3aa25d47e0ab6abbab/transformed/jetified-logback-android-2.0.0-runtime.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/raiser/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/17f8528b15b95f4e98b73ee7482c4884/transformed/jetified-logback-android-2.0.0/jars/classes.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```